# Insert foreign keys in multiple MySQL tables using Python function

Tags: python, mysql

I have multiple tables for which I have to insert foreign keys.
Starting from dictionary (i.e. part of the one I'm using, d_fk = {'Bien_Immo': ['fk_Id_Lot', 'Lot', 'Id']}).
It gives entries to 'create_fk()' function that will insert F_keys.

'Bien_Immo': table in which fk will be inserted
'fk_Id_Lot': name of fk
'Lot': name of parent table
'Id': name of parent column

Here is the code that return an error SQL syntax (1064)

```
def create_fk(name1, name2, name3, name4):
    url = "mysql+pymysql://{user}:{password}@localhost/{db}"
    engine = create_engine(url.format(user='root', password='******', db='data_immo'))
    engine.execute(f"ALTER TABLE {name1}"
                   f"ADD COLUMN {name2},"
                   f"ADD CONSTRAINT {name2}"
                   f"ADD FOREIGN KEY ({name2}) REFERENCES {name3}({name4})"
                   f"ON DELETE CASCADE")

for key in d_fk.keys():
    if isinstance(d_fk[key][0], list):
        for i in range(len(d_fk[key])):
            [n2, n3, n4] = [d_fk[key][i][0], d_fk[key][i][1], d_fk[key][i][2]]
            create_fk(key, n2, n3, n4)
    else:
        [n2, n3, n4] = [d_fk[key][0], d_fk[key][1], d_fk[key][2]]
        create_fk(key, n2, n3, n4)
```

Tank you for your help on this

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the SQL is you want to add a column but you don't specify a datatype for it.

In order for your SQL to work you must specify a datatype that matches the `name4` column datatype.

For instance, if `name4` is `bigint` this will work:

```
engine.execute(f"ALTER TABLE {name1}"
                   f"ADD COLUMN {name2} bigint,"
                   f"ADD CONSTRAINT {name2}"
                   f"ADD FOREIGN KEY ({name2}) REFERENCES {name3}({name4})"
                   f"ON DELETE CASCADE")
```

Comment: Many thanks for answer, I added the type INT (engine.execute(f"ALTER TABLE {name1}"
                   f"ADD COLUMN {name2} INT,"
                   f"ADD FOREIGN KEY ({name2}) REFERENCES {name3}({name4}),"
                   f"DELETE ON CASCADE")), But did not work, still same error message

Comment: Try removing the comma ',' at the end of `REFERENCES {name3}((name4}),"`

Comment: When you are having trouble generating statements, it is a good idea to print the statement and copy&paste to run it on the database: you catch a lot of mistakes :-)

Comment: I removed commas, closed/reopen project but still same error massage

Comment: This two lines are okwhen typing directly in MySQL, ALTER TABLE Bien_Immo
ADD COLUMN fk_Id_Lot int, ADD FOREIGN KEY (fk_Id_Lot) REFERENCES Lot(Id), but if I replace 'fk_Id_Lot', 'Lot' and 'Id' by their related variables, it comes an error message

Answer (score 0):

this works fine

```
engine.execute(f"ALTER TABLE {name1} ADD COLUMN {name2} int, ADD FOREIGN KEY ({name2}) REFERENCES {name3}({name4}) ON DELETE CASCADE")
```